# Aggregate function causing errors in SQL

Tags: sql, sum, aggregate, scada

Trying to establish a production percentage based on a couple of values from the same table with the following statement:

```
SELECT avg(sum([Actual]/
(sum(NULLIF([Team Members],0)/(sum(NULLIF([Actual Min],0)))))))
FROM [Shift Production Log]
WHERE [Date] >= DATEADD(dw, -2, :dvalue) AND
  [Line] = :Lpram
```

And I'm getting the following error:

Cannot perform an aggregate function on an expression containing an aggregate or a subquery.

I should also specify I am doing this through a SCADA system that will place parameters that I bind, thus the "Lpram" and "dvalue". Those work in other statements fine, so it appears my problem is the actual select statement itself. Thank you!

Sample Data:

[image]

Comment: Move your `sum` aggregation to a subquery, and then use `avg` on the derived field.

Answer (score 0):

You have an Aggr function

```
sum([Actual]/
(sum(NULLIF([Team Members],0)/(sum(NULLIF([Actual Min],0))))))
```

Which will be one figure

Then you try to take Avg of this, but this is not scalar.  It's like running

```
select avg(sum(1))
```

That wont work